# jquery syntax related, chain selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery, selector

i guessed this would work well..
but it seems not.

code :

```
$('#kim2').next().children().on('click', function(){
            $(this).parent().prev().css('background-color', 'gray');
            console.log('hmm');
});
```

then how can I specify this.next.children? when I want to use callback function with this keyword?

html:

```
    <div class="kim2">피의자 전과<br />(택일)</div>
    <div id="c" class="kim2b">
                <div id="c1" class="kim2bb">형사처벌 전력<br />없음</div>
                <div id="c2" class="kim2bb">자격정지 이하 <br />이종전과</div>
                <div id="c3" class="kim2bb">5년 이내 <br />집행유예 2회</div>
                <div id="c4" class="kim2bb">5년 이내 <br />3회이상 벌금</div>
                <div id="c5" class="kim2bb">5년 이내 <br />집행유예 </div>
                <div id="c6" class="kim2bb">3년 이내 <br />집행유예</div>
                <div id="c7" class="kim2bb"><p>이종 누범</p> </div>
                <div id="c8" class="kim2bb"><p>동종 누범</p></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$('kim2')` would select elements with **tag name** `kim2`. Such elements don't exist in HTML. Also, whether the traversal is correct or not depends on your document structure, which we don't know about.

Comment: Is kim2 a class or id?

Comment: ah..... my god. it has to be #kim2

Comment: edited done. still not working, what can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to bind the click handler to each of the next element's children (which is what your code does), or bind the click handler to `#kim2` and then when `#kim2` is clicked change the colour of all of the next element's children at once? And have you put that code in a document ready handler, or in a script block that appears after all the elements in question?

Comment: can you show us the html also

Comment: We cannot help you without knowing the document structure. You should also explain what exactly you are trying to do, i.e. which elements you want to target with regard to the document structure.

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: and I want to target #kim2, not children of the next. sorry for the ambiguity, I edited it.

Comment: You don't seem to have an element with **ID** `kim2`.

Comment: ah again, i'm such a bigtime newbie sorry. i will try again..T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `kim2` a class or an id of the element?
You should either do this (for class):

```
    $('.kim2').next().children().on('click', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
        console.log('hmm');
    });
```

Or this (for id):

```
    $('#kim2').next().children().on('click', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
        console.log('hmm');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your ,you dont have id like kim2b.You have class.it would be like

```
$('.kim2').next().children('.kim2b').on('click', function(){    
        $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
        console.log('hmm');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**By Specifing** the child `element selector` may work for you like `span`

```
$('#kim2').next().children('.kim2bb').on('click', function(){
       $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
       console.log('hmm');
});
```

Use **kim2bb** here in `children selector`

Or simply you can use it like,

```
$('.kim2bb').on('click', function(){
       $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
       console.log('hmm');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify to this

```
$('.kim2b').children().on('click', function(){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
            console.log('hmm');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> *" I want to target #kim2, not children of the next"*

OK, you seem to be saying that when the `kim2` element is clicked you want to change the colour of all of the children of the next element. If so, you need `".kim2"` to select by class (not `"#kim2"` that selects by id), and then:

```
$('#kim2').on('click', function() {
       $(this).next().children('.kim2bb').css('background-color', 'gray');
       console.log('hmm');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

kim2 is `classname` not `id` so you have to use class selector like this

```
$('.kim2').next().children().on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
    console.log('hmm');
});
```

Otherwise you can also use `id` of `next` element like this

```
$('#c').children().on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
    console.log('hmm');
});
```